# Make only a few columns of an NSTableView movable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In iTunes, you will see that the first two columns (the first narrow one containing nothing) and the second one containing song name, are not movable. The others are movable.

How can I accomplish this with an NSTableView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the `NSTableViewDelegate` method [`tableView:shouldReorderColumn:toColumn:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView:shouldReorderColumn:toColumn:) to control this behaviour.  From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView:shouldReorderColumn:toColumn:):

> When a column is initially dragged by the user, the delegate is first called with a newColumnIndex value of **`-1`**. Returning **`NO`** will disallow that column from being reordered at all. Returning **`YES`** allows it to be reordered, and the delegate will be called again when the column reaches a new location.

Answer (score 1):

In your table view's delegate, respond to [the `tableView:shouldReorderColumn:toColumn:` message](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView:shouldReorderColumn:toColumn:). See the documentation at that link for exactly what your implementation must do.